# How to look at a txt file for upper and lowercase? Java

Tags: java, file, char

I'm trying to get my code to read a txt file then spit out how many times a certain character comes up.

So if the txt file reads.

"My My how old might you be?"

If I input m, I need it to spit out 3, but with the code below, I keep getting 1. It won't read the uppercase. Help please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName;
    String inputLetter;
    int count = 0;



    fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the filename: ");

    inputLetter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter contained " +
            "in a string.");
    inputLetter.toLowerCase();
    char letterAsChar = inputLetter.charAt(0);

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);




    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String holdLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < holdLine.length(); i++)

        if (holdLine.charAt(i) == letterAsChar ||
        holdLine.charAt(i) == Character.toUpperCase(letterAsChar))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Small idea use lcase and ucase variable in a loop, `inputlc=inputletter.toLowerCase().charAt(0); inputuc=inputletter.toUpperCase().charAt(0);`

Comment: I tried you example , I got result as `3`. You sure the program has problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method toLowerCase and friends returns a String, so you must always save the result:

```
 inputLetter = inputLetter.toLowerCase();
```

It's also better to convert the entire line for simpler processing:

```
 String holdLine = inputFile.nextLine().toLowerCase();

if (holdLine.charAt(i) == letterAsChar){
    count++;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Just to make sure I'm understanding, this only works because I'm forcing the input into a lowercase and every time a line it read from the inputFile its immediately getting changed into lowercase before the if statement.

Comment: Correct. - Your version would have worked as well except for not storing the result of the method call, but one conversion call for the entire string is more efficient than doing it piecemeal.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
Character.toUpperCase(holdLine.charAt(i)))==Character.toUpperCase(letterAsChar))
```

Either compare in lowercase or uppercase on both sides